# `sudo mysqldump` returning 0 bytes

Tags: bash, mysql

I'm writing a backup script for our websites. It `bzip`s the site's document root and then `mysqldump`s the database to a file within the backup directory.

```
# this script is meant to be run as root user

# these are not hardcoded in the real script, just here for simplicity's sake

USERNAME="root"
PASSWORD="password"
HOSTNAME="localhost"
DATABASE="client"

# $BACKUP_PATH equals "~/website-backups/clientname.com/2015-02-04@12:16:00"
# $1 equals "/var/www/vhosts/clientname.com"

# this command runs fine, but the resulting file is 0 bytes
mysqldump -u$USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -h $HOSTNAME $DATABASE > $BACKUP_PATH/$(basename $1).sql
```

If I simply run `mysqldump -uroot -ppassword -h localhost client > clientname.com.sql`, I get a 1.4 Mb file of the correct SQL statements.

[Here's a link to the Bash script on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zwkguzyb).

Why is the `mysqldump` command in my backup script producing a SQL file of 0 bytes length?

Comment: Quote your shell variables (`"$foo"` instead of `$foo`). If your password contains special characters, this will end in great fun otherwise.

Comment: `set -x` is your friend

Comment: Try pasting your script in here... http://www.shellcheck.net/#

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are using it in cron:

try to write the full path if the command is not standard, for example:

`/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u[user] -p[pass] dbname > [file]`